# How do I make a WebKit WebView use a CSS style sheet?

Tags: css, cocoa, macos, webkit, webview

I made an html wich links to a CSS file, open it in browsers, and the styles show correctly.
Then I load it in a WebView and the styles don't show.
I even tried to insert a `<link>` into the DOM from Objective-C, which is my ultimate goal, but neither worked.
Do I have to enable CSS on the webView somehow?

edit:
the CSS include in the html:
`<link rel='StyleSheet' href="file://localhost/Users/petruza/Source/Scrape/build/Debug/Scrape.app/Contents/Resources/Scrape.css" type="text/css" >`

the CSS inserted in the DOM: (I checked and it does get inserted)

```
NSURL *cssUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Scrape.css" withExtension: nil];

DOMDocument* dom = [[web mainFrame] DOMDocument];

[window setTitleWithRepresentedFilename: lastRunScript];

DOMElement* link = [dom createElement:@"link"];

[link setAttribute:@"rel" value:@"StyleSheet"];
[link setAttribute:@"type" value:@"text/css"];
[link setAttribute:@"href" value: [cssUrl absoluteString]];
    
DOMElement* head = (DOMElement*) [[dom getElementsByTagName:@"head"] item:0];
DOMElement* headFirstChild = head.firstElementChild;

if( headFirstChild )    
    [head insertBefore:link refChild:(DOMNode *)headFirstChild];    
else
    [head appendChild:(DOMNode *)link];
```

edit2:
Same exact html shown in my WebView and in Safari:
[image]

Comment: Where's the code?  What does the CSS Includes look like?

Comment: Can't I start a bounty? I don't see much more responses coming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to include an html `<base>` element to tell the webview where it shoul be looking for the css files.

Comment: But the css href is given absolute: `<link rel='StyleSheet' href="file://localhost/Users/petruza/Source/Scrapp/build/Debug/Scrapp.app/Contents/Resources/Scrapp.css" type="text/css" >` and safari gets it correctly without a <base>

Comment: I actually get this value at runtime from the Bundle Resources, and use this same URL for the webview and for an html that I load in a browser, the html displays correctly, but the webView doesn't.

Comment: Your absolute url is wrong. It probably won't work but try this href: `file:///Users/petruza/Source/Scrapp/build/Debug/Scrapp.app/Contents/resources/Scrapp.css`

Comment: Thanks, but it does work even in Safari. I also tried the absolute path without `localhost`, and also tried to reference the original CSS file, not the copy inside the Bundle, all of them work on an external browser and none of them work in my WebView

Comment: Bottomline is this: the *same* html with the same <link> that references the same absolute URL to the CSS, does work on browsers but does not work in my WebView.  
The html does display correctly but without the specified style. (in my WebView)  
What I'm wondering is if the WebView disallows CSS by default or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative would be to use the user stylesheet preference of the WebView:

```
WebView* webView = /* snip */;
webView.preferences.userStyleSheetEnabled = YES;
webView.preferences.userStyleSheetLocation = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"my/stylesheet.css"];
```

Assuming that the style data can be reached with an URL, this is probably the simplest way to do it.

Comment: what about WKWebView?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my bad, I was loading the WebView with a string and not providing a baseURL:
Before:

```
[[web mainFrame]
 loadHTMLString: output
 baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

After:

```
[[web mainFrame]
 loadHTMLString: output
 baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file://localhost/"]];
```

It works now!

Comment: Isn't this what @Femi was trying to tell you all along?  Also, the code above wasn't even part of your OP.  In all fairness, I think you should accept his answer.

Comment: ok, done. But I couldn't force the HTML to have anything, because it would be user-supplied, so no <base> tag could be enforced. The problem was where I was making the load request, which wasn't included in the OP because I didn't realize that then.

Comment: In fact, adding a <base> to the HTML didn't fix it, because the CSS path was absolute, the problem was in loading the page, but anyway, thanks all for answering.